# Create a list named after values from dictionary

Tags: python, list

I have some csv files in a folder that are named as follows

```
'01012017_alp.csv', '01012017_idk.csv', '01012017_kan.csv',    
'01012017_klm.csv', '01022017_kas.csv', '01022017_mlp.csv'
```

The files are named in the format (ddmmyyyy_random3letterstring).

I have also created some empty lists like

```
Jan=[], Feb=[], Mar=[] ...
```

What I wanted to do was add all csv files to the appropriate list matching the 'mm' in the csv file name. For eg:

```
Jan=['01012017_alp.csv', '01012017_idk.csv', '01012017_kan.csv',    
    '01012017_klm.csv']
```

I used a dictionary to retrieve the month from the filename. However, I am stuck on how to append to the correct list.

```
monthDict={'01':'Jan', '02':'Feb', ...... '12':'Dec'}
```

I wrote the following code but did not get the required result. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
filelist = os.listdir(dir_name)
tempmonth=(str(item))[2:4] # I get the key for the value in my month dictionary
for filename in filelist:
    if list(monthDict[tempmonth]):  # Checking if empty lists with month name exist,            
        (monthDict[tempmonth]).append(filename)
```

Also is there anyway I can dynamically create lists from with names matching the values of my dictionary and append the file names to it?

Comment: did you consider changing your dict to be: `{'01': [], '02': [] ...}` and then simply adding each file to the corresponding month key?

Comment: No. I am very new to programming. So is it possible to have list of values against month keys? I may have more than one file name for each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is use the [`globals()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/globals) dict:

```py
filelist = os.listdir(dir_name)

for filename in filelist:
    tempmonth = filename[2:4]
    l = globals().setdefault(monthDict[tempmonth], [])
    l.append(filename)
```

The [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method grabs an item from the dict, but returns the second argument if the key was not found. This way you don't even need to define all lists pre-hand. For example, after running this code with the list of files you provided:

```py
>>> print(Jan)
['01012017_alp.csv', '01012017_idk.csv', '01012017_kan.csv', '01012017_klm.csv']
>>> print(Feb)
['01022017_kas.csv', '01022017_mlp.csv']
>>>
```

---

Alternatively, as I suggested in the comments, you could simply use your `monthDict` to save lists of files:

```py
filelist = os.listdir(dir_name)

monthDict = {}
for filename in filelist:
    tempmonth = filename[2:4]
    l = monthDict.setdefault(tempmonth, [])
    l.append(filename)
```

And to access a month you can do:

```py
>>> print(monthDict['01'])
['01012017_alp.csv', '01012017_idk.csv', '01012017_kan.csv', '01012017_klm.csv']
>>> for jan_file in monthDict['01']:
...     print(jan_file)
01012017_alp.csv
01012017_idk.csv
01012017_kan.csv
01012017_klm.csv
```

Comment: In the second case, will I be able to access each value in the list of files? Or should I convert it to another list and access it?

Comment: What do you mean @zorbamj? in the second case you will have a dictionary called `monthDict` of the form `{'01': [...], '02': [...], ...}` where the keys are codes of the months and the values are lists of files corresponding to that month. You can see that very clearly in the last example I posted

Comment: I understand that. If I `print(monthDict['01'])` I would get the list of files in Jan. My question is, how do I access each value in the list. For eg: If I want to read each csv file in the month.
For that requirement I should go with the first method right?

Also as suggested when I tried printing 'print(Jan)`, it console gives me: 
`File "Ex03_csvcreater.py", line 72, in displaycons
    print(Jan)
NameError: name 'Jan' is not defined`
I should assume lists `Jan, Feb` etc are not created?

Comment: @zorbamj For your first question: both methods are the same. In the end you get a list of files and you can do with it whatever you want like with any list. I have updated the example. For your second question, works fine for me...

Comment: @zorbamj if you are calling this as a function from another file so the first method will be problematic. `globals` - as much as its name implies the opposite - changes only the scope of the module it is in. So if you call this from another file and then expect to use `Jan` it won't work as `Jan` will be now defined in the same module of the function

Comment: I called it as a function from the same program and it kept on throwing the NameError. I went ahead with the second method and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
file_names = ['01012017_alp.csv', '01012017_idk.csv', '01012017_kan.csv',    
'01012017_klm.csv', '01022017_kas.csv', '01022017_mlp.csv']

monthDict = {'01': [] , '02': [], '03': [], '04': [], '05': [], '06': [], '07': [], '08': [], '09': [], '10': [], '11': [], '12': []}

for file in file_names:
    print(file[2:4])
    for key, value in monthDict.items():
        if file[2:4] == key:
            value.append(file)

print(monthDict)
```